# How can I change the background color on button click using an array? Current code used inside

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

Newbie here. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and would be appreciative of some guidance. Here's the JS I have:

```
const colors = ['#ee5253', '#00bce4', '#222f3e']
const i = 0
const button = document.getElementById('button')


button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  i = i < colors.length ? ++i : 0;
document.querySelector('body').style.background = colors[i]
})
```

document.querySelector works if I just replace "colors[i]" with a color.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a value to a constant.

Don't declare `i` as a constant.

You also should be checking whether `i` is smaller than the length of the array *minus 1*, since arrays are 0 indexed.

```js
const colors = ['#ee5253', '#00bce4', '#222f3e']
var i = 0
const button = document.getElementById('button')


button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  i = i < colors.length - 1 ? ++i : 0;
  document.querySelector('body').style.background = colors[i]
})
```

```html
<button id="button">Button</button>
```